# Givens Rotation in Eigen with sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen

Within my own C++ implementation of a QR decomposition, through the Givens rotations to set the rotation matrix to the identity matrix I'm trying to use [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html) more versatile Eigen's class for sparse matrices. In fact, the common compressed row/column storage format does not support the 'setIdentity' method' the algorithm calls for.

The snippet I added to my code does not compile, and the Eigen help is quite obscure to me in this regard:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse> 
SparseMatrix<double,ColMajor,int> G(m,m);  

G = G.setIdentity(m,m);
```

Any suggestions? How do I define the pre-processor symbol `EIGEN_SPARSEMATRIX_PLUGIN`?

[BTW: is there any pre-packaged good implementation out there? Neither Eigen nor Armadillo seem to provide it]

Answer (score 1):

This compiles/runs fine for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

int main() {
    constexpr int m = 10;
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::ColMajor,int> G(m,m);
    G.setIdentity();
    std::cout << G << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I built via

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo
```

You may need to add `-I /usr/local/include/Eigen/` to make sure it finds you Eigen headers.